# spring batch 5 without datasource

Tags: configuration, spring-batch, datasource, java-17

I'm trying to migrate my spring batch from v4 to v5, but this batch doesn't use a database.
The problem is when i'm trying to run the batch with the news changes, i got this error : JobRepository is mandatory

Is it now mandatory to have a datasource on spring batch 5 ? Or can we avoid it like old version by declaring the override method "setDatasource" ?

Thanks a lot guys.

I tried to exclude DataSourceAutoConfiguration on the application and i searched how to disable it on application.properties but i found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JobRepository` has always been mandatory in Spring Batch. What has changed between v4 and v5 is that the Map-based implementation (that was used by default when there is no datasource defined) was removed.

Therefore, you either have to define a datasource (could be an embedded one) and use the JDBC-based `JobRepository`, or provide a custom `JobRepository` implementation according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. He needs anyway a datasource :  java.lang.IllegalStateException: DataSource must not be null. 
So the fact is that we can't use spring batch without an embedded datasource anymore ? 
I tried to implement myself a jobRepository like this :

`@Bean
 public JobRepository jobRepository() {
  JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
  factory.setDataSource(null);
  factory.setDatabaseType("H2");
  try {
   return factory.getObject();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
 }`

Comment: You used the `JobRepositoryFactoryBean` which is the factory bean that creates a JDBC-based job repository, which requires a datasource. If you really want to avoid having to use a datasource (even an embedded one), you need a custom implementation of the `JobRepository` interface that discards meta-data. Something like `NoOpJobRepository` with empty methods (but some features won't work unless you correctly implement the methods).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. That's helped me a lot to understand. But now i implemted my custom repository but i got another error : StepExecution must already be saved (have an id assigned). I implemented my job and my step like the new version https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/job/running.html on the section "running a job" . What does it mean? Which id is it reffer?